# Firebase to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I´m using Firebase to store same app data and then when I need to get and push to array and iterate works fine but I can´t iterate Images

Firebase data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVV6M.png

this is my code on Ionic.

```
this.database.list('/posts', { preserveSnapshot: true})
      .subscribe(snapshots => {
          snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
           this.postArray.push(snapshot.val())
          });
      })

 <ion-card  *ngFor="let post of postArray" no-shadow> 

  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of postArray.images">
      <p>{{image}}</p>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title> {{post.title}} </ion-card-title>
      <p> {{post.body}} </p>
    </ion-card-content>
```

thanks

Comment: This is not the proper way to display an image. Your image wioo be a url. Do <img [url]="image">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is wrong, you're trying to iterate over `postArray` instead of `post`.

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of post.images">
    <p>{{image}}</p>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

<ion-card-content>
  <ion-card-title> {{post.title}} </ion-card-title>
  <p> {{post.body}} </p>
</ion-card-content>
```

Also you should look into the `async` pipe, you could optimise your code slightly - remove the need for subscriptions.

```
this.postArray = this.database.list('/posts', { preserveSnapshot: true});

<ion-card  *ngFor="let post of postArray | async" no-shadow> 

    <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of post.images">
      <p>{{image}}</p>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title> {{post.title}} </ion-card-title>
    <p> {{post.body}} </p>
  </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>
```

Finally, if you are using the `.subscribe` within your controller, don't forget you need to unsubscribe on `ngOnDestroy` or after you've finished processing the data. If you don't want to unsubscribe and you're trying to preserve the snapshot you could look at the `.first` method.

```
// Using .subscribe - Need to unsubscribe
this.posts$ = this.database.list('/posts', { preserveSnapshot: true })
  .subscribe

// ...

ngOnDestroy() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.posts$.unsubscribe();
  });
}

// Using .first - No need to unsubscribe
this.database.list('/posts', { preserveSnapshot: true})
  .first()
  .subscribe(snapshots => {
```